# Breath first search, all paths to a goal in a graph

Tags: python, algorithm, graph-algorithm

I'm playing around with BFS, while trying to teach myself Python 3. Currently I'm trying to get all paths from the start to the goal, in a graph.

The graph is setup like:

```
graph = {
    A : [B, C],
    B : [D, E],
    C : [F],
    F : [B]
}
```

So, there's a path from F to B. The issue I'm running in to is as follows: since some nodes are set to visited, the algorithm can't run over them again. I can change this, of course, but then I'm wondering what 'stop' condition I should use.

My code is like this:

```
initial = A
goal = D 
# So there are 2 routes: 
#   A -> C -> F -> B -> D
#   A -> B  -> D

frontier = queue.Queue()
frontier.put(initial)

backtracker = { }
paths = []

# until I find a halting condition.    
while True:

    node = frontier.get()
    print('Popping: ' + node.name)

    node.isOpen = False

    if node in graph:
        for child in graph[node]:
            print('Expanding: ' + node.name + ' -> ' + child.name)

            backtracker.update( { child : node } )

            if child.name == goal.name:
                path = backtrack(backtracker, initial, goal)
                paths.append(path)

                backtracker = {}
                goal.isOpen = True
                initial.isOpen = True
                frontier = queue.Queue()
                frontier.put(initial)

            if child.isOpen:
                print('Putting: ' + child.name)
                frontier.put(child)
```

So in this case, the route A -> B -> D is found, but this sets B to closed, so the algorithm can't visit it anymore to find A -> C -> F -> B -> D. I'm starting to think in circles, so any hint (rather a hint then a full solution!!!) would be very much appreciated.

And let's ignore cases like 'A -> C -> F -> B -> A -> C -> F -> B -> D' etc (which isn't possible anyway, since there's no path from B -> A defined).

Comment: What about A -> C -> F -> B -> A -> C -> F -> B -> D? Or A -> C -> F -> B -> A -> C -> F -> B -> A -> C -> F -> B -> D? Or A -> C -> F -> B -> A -> C -> F -> B -> A -> C -> F -> B -> A -> C -> F -> B -> D? Or... OK, I think you get my meaning. Finding all paths in a cyclic graph is troublesome.

Comment: This is not possible. There is no path from B->A, as stated in the graph definition.

Comment: I figured you're referring to an undirected graph. If there's no edge (B, A), then where is the circle?

Comment: * Perhaps my naming was wrong, as you might expect I'm rather new to this, updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BFS tries to build a spanning tree. If you want to get the *shortest path* in the process, you can stop when you find the goal node for the first time - this is a typical use case for BFS.

However if you want to find *all* paths, I think the stop condition is that <strike>you have visited all nodes, so the spanning tree is complete</strike> there are no further nodes you can access from the nodes you have visited already. You can not stop sooner, since even the very last node you are going to visit, may have an unidirectional edge leading to the goal node, revealing a new path (though the least optimal one).

---

When writing the answer above I probably just partially understood the question. If you are asking about generating the paths at the end, and given a configuration like

```
 A--------->B-------->C
  \       /  \       /
   \->D->/    \->E->/
```

you want to find all of ABC,ADBC,ABEC and ADBEC, I think you will need to do a full traversal on this valid-paths-graph in a recursive way, a DFS (just on this sub-graph, all possible attempts will generate a valid path). So the BFS-pass could be used to reduce the original graph into a graph containing actual (and possibly redundant) paths only, but then a DFS is needed to actually generate all of them separately.

Comment: Haven't done anything with DFS yet, but I'll do so today. So I'll end up with some combination of the 2 to do what I want to achieve. Thank you!